# How to import large csv file and perform operations

Tags: python, bigdata

I have a problems with opening a large csv file (>5GB) and perform some simple operations on it. I have made this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os                                                                   
import glob                                                                 

os.chdir('C:\\Users\\data')                                   
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', low_memory=False, header=None, names=   ['column1','column2', 'column3'])
df
```

Even setting low_meemory false it does not work. I used the following code that I found in this site but it does not work either.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os                                                                   
import glob 

os.chdir('C:\\Users\\data')    
mylist = []

for chunk in  pd.read_csv('SME_all.csv', sep=';', chunksize=20000):
mylist.append(chunk)

big_data = pd.concat(mylist, axis= 0)
del mylist

df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', low_memory=False, header=None, 
error_bad_lines = False, names=['column1','column2', 'column3'])
df
```

Any suggestion? Should I consider using other application such as Apache Spark?

Comment: Could you elaborate on *does not work*... Are your running out of memory or something else? What are the simple operations you wish to perform - could they be applied on a row-by-row basis or do they require context of an entire DataFrame?

Comment: The `csv` module allows to process a csv file record by record and it very good at processing huge files... provided processing per record makes sense for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of approaches.

Perhaps the simplest is to split your CSV into multiple files.  This only works if you don't need to aggregate the data in any way, such as groupby.

You can try specifying dtypes on import, otherwise Pandas may interpret columns as objects which will take up more memory.

You can iterate over the CSV using python's built in CSV reader, and perform operations on each row if that's the type of work you're trying to do.

You can look at Dask, or using PySpark on Google's dataproc or Azure's databricks.